# WooCommerce : Add variation for a downloadable product

Tags: woocommerce

guys! I want to add variation for a downloadable product, in WooCommerce plugin. When I select the "Variable Product" from Product Data options, checkbox download and checkbox virtual are disappear. What can I do?

Comment: I had the same question, it wasn't necessarily intuitive working in WooCommerce. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in this image, [image: t] once you add some attributes, set them as variables. You can then chose downloadable and virtual.

The [woo documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/product-variations/) explains it in more detail.